# Forcing zeros to appear in Count

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012

The following code takes a table containing vehicle names, and a table containing region names and combines them into a results table.
I then perform a COUNT on the results table to show how many vehicles there are per region.

I need to amend the code to force ALL regions and ALL vehicles to be counted up.  Currently the COUNT statement does not show any regions that contain no vehicles (I have manually deleted some entries from the results to show this).  Can anyone illustrate a quick way to do this?   I am using SQL 2012 and hoped there would be an easy solution...

[image]

For the purposes of answering the question please assume that the two original tables are no longer accessible, and we are now only working with @tbl_results.  Thank you.

Note: I know I can do this directly from the vehicle and region tables but I need to use a table variable of results for other processes in my real work.

```
DECLARE @tbl_vehicles TABLE (vehicleID int, vehicleName nvarchar(100))
DECLARE @tbl_regions TABLE (regionID int, regionName nvarchar(100))
DECLARE @tbl_results TABLE (regionID int, regionName nvarchar(100), vehicleID int, vehicleName nvarchar(100))

INSERT INTO @tbl_regions (regionID, regionName) VALUES (1, 'England')
INSERT INTO @tbl_regions (regionID, regionName) VALUES (2, 'United States')
INSERT INTO @tbl_regions (regionID, regionName) VALUES (3, 'Arctic')

INSERT INTO @tbl_vehicles (vehicleID, vehicleName) VALUES (1, 'Planes')
INSERT INTO @tbl_vehicles (vehicleID, vehicleName) VALUES (2, 'Trains')
INSERT INTO @tbl_vehicles (vehicleID, vehicleName) VALUES (3, 'Automobiles')

DECLARE @i INT
SET @i = 0 

WHILE @i < 100
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @tbl_results
            (regionID, regionName, vehicleID, vehicleName) 
        SELECT
            r.regionID, r.regionName, v.vehicleID, v.vehicleName 
        FROM
            @tbl_regions r CROSS JOIN
            @tbl_vehicles v 
        WHERE
            (r.regionID = CAST(RAND() * 4 AS INT)) AND
            (v.vehicleID = CAST(RAND() * 4 AS INT)) 
        SET @i = @i + 1
    END

-- remove trains in the arctic for count example
DELETE FROM @tbl_results WHERE (regionID=3) AND (vehicleID=2)

-- this statement needs to include ALL vehicles and ALL regions (even if no vehicles are found at a region)
SELECT 
    regionName,
    vehicleName,
    COUNT(*) as VehicleCount
FROM
    @tbl_results 
GROUP BY
    regionID,
    regionName,
    vehicleID,
    vehicleName
ORDER BY regionName, vehicleName
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  r.regionName
,       v.vehicleName
,       COUNT(res.vehicleName) as VehicleCount
FROM    (
        select  distinct regionName
        from    @tbl_results
        ) r
CROSS JOIN 
        (
        select  distinct vehicleName
        from    @tbl_results
        ) v
LEFT OUTER JOIN
        @tbl_results res
ON      r.regionName = res.regionName
        AND v.vehicleName = res.vehicleName
GROUP BY
        r.regionName
,       v.vehicleName
ORDER BY
        r.regionName
,       v.vehicleName
```

Comment: Won't the `COUNT(*)` mess the results?. You should do the count on some column of the `@tbl_results` table

Comment: @Lamak: You're right, `count(*)` incorrectly returns 1 if no row is found for a region+vehicle group

Comment: Super, thanks.  I changed the join columns to the ID columns (just to eliminate any possible of two vehicles/regions have the same name but a different ID) and it works well.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @tbl_vehicles TABLE (vehicleID int, vehicleName nvarchar(100))
DECLARE @tbl_regions TABLE (regionID int, regionName nvarchar(100))
DECLARE @tbl_results TABLE (regionID int, regionName nvarchar(100), 
                            vehicleID int, vehicleName nvarchar(100))

INSERT INTO @tbl_regions (regionID, regionName) VALUES (1, 'England')
INSERT INTO @tbl_regions (regionID, regionName) VALUES (2, 'United States')
INSERT INTO @tbl_regions (regionID, regionName) VALUES (3, 'Arctic')

INSERT INTO @tbl_vehicles (vehicleID, vehicleName) VALUES (1, 'Planes')
INSERT INTO @tbl_vehicles (vehicleID, vehicleName) VALUES (2, 'Trains')
INSERT INTO @tbl_vehicles (vehicleID, vehicleName) VALUES (3, 'Automobiles')

DECLARE @i INT
SET @i = 0 

WHILE @i < 100
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO @tbl_results
            (regionID, regionName, vehicleID, vehicleName) 
        SELECT
            r.regionID, r.regionName, v.vehicleID, v.vehicleName 
        FROM
            @tbl_regions r CROSS JOIN
            @tbl_vehicles v 
        WHERE
            (r.regionID = CAST(RAND() * 4 AS INT)) AND
            (v.vehicleID = CAST(RAND() * 4 AS INT)) 
        SET @i = @i + 1
    END

-- remove trains in the arctic for count example
DELETE FROM @tbl_results WHERE (regionID=3) AND (vehicleID=2)

-- this statement needs to include ALL vehicles 
-- and ALL regions (even if no vehicles are found at a region)
SELECT 
    R.regionName,
    VE.vehicleName,
    ISNULL(COUNT(RES.regionID),0) as VehicleCount
FROM @tbl_regions R
CROSS JOIN @tbl_vehicles VE
LEFT JOIN @tbl_results RES
    ON R.regionID = RES.regionID AND VE.vehicleID = RES.vehicleID
GROUP BY
     R.regionName,
    VE.vehicleName
ORDER BY R.regionName, VE.vehicleName
```

Comment: A `cross join` without `distinct` results in a lot of duplicate rows.  This query will return counts that are way too high.

Comment: @Andomar Well, since those tables are unique I don't really see the problem. But yeah, in case they are not, then this will show duplicate results.

Comment: Ah, you're joining on `@tbl_vehicles` not `@tbl_results`.  Prolly better, +1

Comment: @Andomar Yes, no need to do `DISTINCT` (in this case, at least)

Answer (score 1):

I'd do it this way:

```
WITH VehicleRegions AS
(
  SELECT
    *
  FROM
    tbl_vehicles,
    tbl_regions
 )
SELECT 
  VehicleRegions.VehicleName,
  VehicleRegions.RegionName,
  COUNT(tbl_results.regionID)
FROM
  VehicleRegions
  LEFT JOIN tbl_results ON VehicleRegions.VehicleID = tbl_results.VehicleID AND VehicleRegions.RegionID = tbl_results.RegionID
GROUP BY
  VehicleRegions.VehicleName,
  VehicleRegions.RegionName
```

See [Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/fadce/3)

In the fiddle I used tables rather than table variables but the idea stands. Create a Common Table Expression that contains all of the vehicle and region pairs. Then do a Count(results.[AnyColumn]). If you do a Count(*) then NULL values in the result will be counted. You don't want that. You only want to count where the results contain a value.

Answer (score 0):

You can accomplish your goal with a combination of left join and isNull.  The general idea looks like this:

```
select f1, f2, isNull(count(*), 0) records
from t1 left join t2 on something
where whatever
group by f1, f2
```

You can add the details.

Comment: count(*) will never be null

Comment: Agreed with Tobsey. Count will always return a value or 0-zero. No need to isNulll() or NVL()